# detect linebreak from textbox in c#

Tags: c#, html, textbox, line-breaks

I have a html text box for writing an e-mail. I insert the input into a database using c#. when I print it, i use innerhtml so if the message contains `<br/>` it will replace it in a line break.
I want to keep the line breaks as the writer wrote, for that I have to detect the line breakes and replace them with `<br/>`s
I want to know how can I detect line breaks in c# so I can replace it in `<br/>` when I insert it to the database?

Comment: `emailText = emailText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>");`? Like [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ngh3Wn)

Comment: @MindSwipe thank you so so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think that this one can help you solve the problem.

```
var convertNewLineToBr = emailText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, @"<br/>");
```